# How to use DialogPlus in RVAdapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use this library **https://github.com/orhanobut/dialogplus**. How to use and call position of RV in DialogPlus.

```
public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        Button btn_edit, btn_delete;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            .
            .
            .              
            btn_edit = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
            btn_delete = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
            btn_edit.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn_delete.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == btn_edit.getId()) {
                DialogPlus dialog = DialogPlus.newDialog(context)
                   .setContentHolder(new ViewHolder(R.layout.dialog_edit))
                   .create();
                dialog.show();
            EditText brandName = (EditText) dialog.getHolderView().findViewById(R.id.brandName);
            EditText price = (EditText) dialog.getHolderView().findViewById(R.id.price);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you found anything because I also stuck in pass holder object in setcontentholder(holder)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library 
Click [here](https://github.com/ma7madfawzy/dialogPlus)
by then you can do this

```
 CustomLayoutDialog dialog = new DialogPlusBuilder().buildCustomLayoutDialog(R.layout.dialog_edit);
                dialog.showNow(getChildFragmentManager(), "dialog_edit");
 DialogEditBinding languageDialogBinding=(DialogEditBinding) dialog.getCustomLayoutBinding();
 languageDialogBinding.recycler.set(...);
```

Comment: Add some description about the code and what it does.

Comment: this code creates a dialog that inflates dialog_edit.xml, as for the getCustomLayoutBinding() method, it returns a ViewDataBinding instance of the inflated view that can be used to navigate through your layout simply. there is anoth method called getCustomLayoutView() that rerurns a view instance , you can use view.findViewById(...) to access yourlayout views .